# Nuxt3 Sitemap Generation

Tags: routes, sitemap, dynamically-generated, nuxt3, sitemap.xml

I'm generating the sitemap within a site with dynamic routes. I'm using nuxt version 3.
According to the documentation provided here, to create the sitemap in a site with dynamic routes it is necessary to create the folder /server/routes/sitemap.xml.ts file.

Inside the file i put this code it seems according to the documentation

```
import { serverQueryContent } from '#content/server'
import { SitemapStream, streamToPromise } from 'sitemap'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
// Fetch all documents
const docs = await serverQueryContent(event).find()
const sitemap = new SitemapStream({
    hostname: 'https://example.com'
})

for (const doc of docs) {
    sitemap.write({
        url: doc._path,
        changefreq: 'monthly'
    })
}
sitemap.end()

return streamToPromise(sitemap)
})
```

This error is returned

```
[worker reload] [worker init] Package import specifier "#content/server" is not 
defined in package /Users/myuser/Desktop/websites/mysite/nuxt- 
app/package.json imported from /Users/myuser/Desktop/websites/mysite.it/nuxt- 
app/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs
```

I can't find anything about it

Comment: There is a Sitemap Module: https://nuxtseo.com/sitemap/

Answer (score 0):

you need to install nuxt content module.

Here is the link

https://content.nuxtjs.org/get-started

1. npm install --save-dev @nuxt/content
2. nuxt.config.ts
   modules: [
   '@nuxt/content'
   ],
3. create a directory called 'content' in the root of the project.
4. Then, create markdown files inside content directory for all of your routes. for example , for '/' route, create index.md
5. It should be working fine.